# WP-API Content showing null

Tags: wp-api

I am working on a decoupled theme for myself and I've worked with WP-API in the past and it was easy to get the post content. For some reason this go around I am having issues getting the content. I go to the end point in my browser or use any method to get the end point for a post or page and the content shows the following:

```
content":{"rendered":null,"protected":false}
```

Comment: Are you using a page builder or anything like that? Does the `post_content` column in the database for that post contain any content?

Comment: Nope I did download Gutenberg. That could be it? I should try to disable that I suppose. My aim is to build this with Gutenberg though so if there is more I need to do to get the content with it then I'll need to know.

Comment: Tried to disable Gutenberg and it is doing the same thing. I also checked the database to be sure and it has content there. I knew it did but I thought I'd double check to be certain.

Comment: Gutenberg content is stored in the post content, so that wouldn't be it (some page builders don't work that way, which is why I asked). Did you look in the Database? How are you making the request?

Comment: Well I am just using the endpoint
http://localhost:8888/personal/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1

But if I go to that url it shows the same thing. I've tried with ajax or wp_remote_get(); and both return the same thing. I am not using any kind of authentication at this point. I do plan to add that if I need to do actual ajax calls in the future. Right now I have a .js.php file that I am using wp_remote_get() to store everything as variables in the file.

Comment: The post ID is definitely `1`?

Comment: Yeah I have looked on the backend as well as in the database.

Comment: Like it shows the title in the API results and other information about it. Just not the excerpt or content.